# Extraer columna maximo

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer un programa que pide los siguientes requisitos:

1. Definirá una matriz bidimensional de enteros, que podemos llamar mat, de dimensiones
   físicas FIL x COL. Tanto FIL como COL será constantes declaradas a nivel global en el
   programa.
2. Definirá un vector de enteros, que podemos llamar vec, de dimensión física FIL.
3. Solicitará que se tecleen las dimensiones efectivas filas y columnas de la matriz mat,
   validando que estén comprendidas entre 1 y FIL, y 1 y COL respectivamente. Se repetirá
   la solicitud de cada dimensión hasta que se teclee un valor en rango correcto.
4. Solicitará que se tecleen un número entero (numero), validando que estén comprendido
   entre 1 y FIL*COL. Se repetirá la solicitud hasta que se teclee un valor en rango correcto.
5. Cargará la matriz mat utilizando la función cargarMatriz que se describe posteriormente.
6. Presentará en pantalla la matriz mat utilizando la función verMatriz que se describe
   posteriormente.
7. Obtendrá la columna de mat con el valor máximo, utilizando la función
   extraeColumnaMaximo que se describe posteriormente.
8. Presentará en pantalla la columna anteriormente obtenida, utilizando la función
   verColumna que se describe posteriormente.

Las funciones mencionadas son las siguientes:
Función cargarMatriz

Recibirá 4 parámetros formales:

• Primer parámetro formal, matrizA. Será un parámetro adecuado para poder recibir una matriz como la descrita anteriormente, mat.

• Segundo y tercer parámetro formal, nfil, y ncol. Será de tipo int, adecuados para poder recibir las dimensiones efectivas de matrizA.
• Cuarto parámetro formal, num. Será un número entero. El leído en el módulo llamador.

La función devolverá la matriz recibida cargada con valores según el siguiente algoritmo:

• Se coloca en el elemento de índice [0][0] el valor entero recibido (num).

• Se recorre por filas la matriz y se calcula sucesivamente cada valor a colocar como el anterior colocado + 3, el anterior colocado - 4, el anterior colocado + 5, el anterior colocado - 6, etc…

Función verMatriz

Recibirá 3 parámetros formales:

• Primer parámetro formal, matrizA. Será un parámetro adecuado para poder recibir una matriz como la descrita anteriormente, mat.

• Segundo y tercer parámetro formal, nfil, y ncol. Será de tipo int, adecuados para poder recibir las dimensiones efectivas de matrizA.

La función presentará en pantalla la matriz recibida.

Función verColumna

Recibirá 2 parámetros formales:

• Primer parámetro formal, vectorX. Será un parámetro adecuado para poder recibir un vector como el descrito anteriormente, vec.

• Segundo parámetro formal, dim. Será de tipo int, adecuados para poder recibir la dimensión efectiva de vectorX.

La función presentará en pantalla el vector recibido.

Función extraeColumnaMaximo

Recibirá 4 parámetros formales:

• Primer parámetro formal, matrizA. Será un parámetro adecuado para poder recibir una matriz como la descrita anteriormente, mat.

• Segundo y tercer parámetro formal, nfil, y ncol. Será de tipo int, adecuados para poder recibir las dimensiones efectivas de matrizA.

• Cuarto parámetro formal, vectorX. Será un parámetro adecuado para poder devolver un vector como el descrito anteriormente, vec.

La función además devolverá un valor tipo int como valor de retorno.

La función internamente deberá buscar, recorriendo por columnas la matrizA, el valor máximo de los elementos de la misma, y devolverá, en el cuarto parámetro formal, la columna que contiene ese valor máximo, es decir, debe copiar en vectorX todos los valores almacenados dicha columna.

En el caso de que existan varios valores iguales al máximo, deberá devolver la columna correspondiente al último encontrado.

Está claro que la dimensión efectiva de vectorX no es necesario devolverla porque será igual que el número de filas efectivas, nfil, de matrizA.

En cuanto al valor de retorno de la función,

− Será
-1 si los parámetros recibidos no superan las validaciones siguientes:

− alguno de los punteros de la matriz o el vector está a NULL, o

− las dimensiones efectivas de la matriz tienen valor negativo, o cero o superior a las dimensiones físicas.

− Será cero si los parámetros recibidos son validados correctamente.

Mi codigo es el siguiente, pero me saltan errores que no se como arreglarlos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FIL 20
#define COL 20
#define MIN 1


void propiedad (void);
void cargarMatriz(int (*)[],int,int,int);
void verMatriz(int (*)[],int,int);
void verColumna(int *,int);
int extraeColumnaMaximo(int (*)[],int,int,int *);


int main (void)
{
int mat[FIL][COL],vec[FIL];
int f,c,n1,n2;
propiedad();

do
{
    printf("Introduzca filas deseadas del vector bidimensional: 
");
    scanf("%d",&f);
    printf("Introduzca columnas deseadas del vector 
bidimensional: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    if (f<MIN || f>FIL || c<MIN || c>COL)
    {
        printf("Dimension erronea.\n");
    }
}
while (f<MIN || f>FIL || c<MIN || c>COL);

do
{
    printf("Introduzca dimension deseada del vector: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);

    if (n1<MIN || n1>FIL*COL)
    {
        printf("Dimension erronea.\n");
    }
}
while (n1<MIN || n1>FIL*COL);

printf("Introduzca un valor: ");
scanf("%d",&n2);
cargarMatriz(mat,f,c,n2);

verMatriz(mat,f,c);
extraeColumnaMaximo(mat,f,c,vec);
verColumna(vec,n1);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void cargarMatriz(int (*matrizA)[COL], int nfil, int ncol, int 
num)
{
int i,j,anterior=0,contador=3;
for (i=0;i<nfil;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<ncol;j++)
    {
        if(i==0 && j==0)
        {
            matrizA[0][0]=num;
            anterior=matrizA[0][0];
        }
        else
        {
        matrizA[i][j]=anterior+contador;
        anterior=matrizA[i][j];
        contador++;
        contador=-contador;
        }
    }
}
}

void verMatriz(int (*matrizA)[COL], int nfil, int ncol)
{
int i,j;
printf ("\nNumeros introducidos: \n");
for (i=0;i<nfil;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<ncol;i++)
    {
        printf ("%3d",matrizA[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

void verColumna(int *vectorX, int dim)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<dim;i++)
{
    printf ("%3d",vectorX[i]);
}
}

int extraeColumnaMaximo(int (*matrizA)[COL], int nfil, int ncol, 
int *vectorX)
{
int j,i,k,maximo,valor;
maximo=matrizA[0][0];
for (j=0;j<ncol;j++)
{
    for (i=0;i<nfil;i++)
    {
        if (matrizA[i][j]>maximo)
        {
            maximo=matrizA[i][j];
            valor=j;
        }
    }
}
for (i=0;i<nfil;i++)
{
    for (k=0;k<nfil;k++)
    {
        vectorX[k]=matrizA[i][valor];
    }
}
if(matrizA==NULL || nfil<=0 || nfil>FIL || ncol<=0 || ncol>COL)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

void propiedad(void)
{
printf("===========================================================\n");
printf("||");
printf("                                                       ||\n");
printf("||");
printf("                                                       ||\n");
printf("||");printf("         Codigo creado por Alvaro Garcia Saez");
printf("          ||\n");
printf("||");printf("       Copyright%c Todos los derechos reservados",184);
printf("        ||\n");
printf("||");
printf("                                                       ||\n");
printf("||");
printf("                                                       ||\n");  
printf("===========================================================\n");
printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Los parametros de las funciones son `int*`, y les pasas un `int[][]`. De ahí es donde salen los errores. Cambia `int*` por `int**` y debería funcionar.

Comment: @Pablochaches lo he probado pero me sigue tirando este error:          expected int ** but argument is of type int (*)[20]

Comment: Que raro, en mi compilador me lo saca solo como un warning. Bueno, entonces en lugar de `int**` usa `int[FIL][COL]`.  Ahora que lo compile me di cuenta de otra cosa. `MIN<f<FIL` no hace lo que tu crees, el operador `<` no funciona en cadena. Tiene que ser `(MIN < f && f < FIL)`.

Comment: @Pablochaches El error del expected lo arreglé poniendo (*)[]. Con eso ya no me salta. La comprobación de mayor y menor muchas gracias, ya lo he arreglado. Ahora no me tira ningun error, pero no me lo hace bien. Después de poner el valor, salen muchos numeros, el primero si es el que introduzco, pero los siguientes no. He editado el codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: Al compilarlo con el ASAN y dándole como entradas puros `1`s me dio el error: `AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow`. Si las entradas que le di podrían ser validas para tu programa significa que en algún lugar estas escribiendo a memoria que no te corresponde. Si no lo son seria bueno que compartieras las entradas que le das tu para que lo pueda probar correctamente.

Comment: @Pablochaches Los valores que yo le doy son: 4 para las filas, 5 para las columnas, 5 para el vector y el último también un 5. Después de poner este último valor saltan muchos números hasta que se queda pillado el programa y se cierra, me imagino que será el error que me mencionas.

Comment: Ya encontre el problema, voy a poner la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría que aprendieras a usar mas herramientas, ya que para este
tipo de problemas son muy útiles y te ahorraran tiempo y dolores de cabeza.

La primera de estas es el
[ASAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Este verificara que no
cometas errores con la memoria. Errores del tipo leer y escribir fuera del
tamaño de los arrays, que es lo que esta sucediendo aquí.

Al correr tu código con el ASAN nos da como resultado:

```
==8588==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x003e24bff8e0 at pc 0x7ff7ea161ee5 bp 0x003e24bff1a0 sp 0x003e24bff1e8
READ of size 4 at 0x003e24bff8e0 thread T0
    #0 0x7ff7ea161ee4 in verMatriz (C:\Users\pabsa\tempc\a.exe+0x140001ee4)
    #1 0x7ff7ea161848 in main (C:\Users\pabsa\tempc\a.exe+0x140001848)
    #2 0x7ff7ea1a6607 in invoke_main d:\A01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
    #3 0x7ff7ea1a6607 in __scrt_common_main_seh d:\A01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
    #4 0x7ffcc0477033  (C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x180017033)
    #5 0x7ffcc18e2650  (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x180052650)

Address 0x003e24bff8e0 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 1632 in frame
    #0 0x7ff7ea16100f in main (C:\Users\pabsa\tempc\a.exe+0x14000100f)

  This frame has 6 object(s):
    [32, 1632) 'mat' <== Memory access at offset 1632 overflows this variable
    [1760, 1840) 'vec'
    [1872, 1876) 'f'
    [1888, 1892) 'c'
    [1904, 1908) 'n1'
    [1920, 1924) 'n2'
```

Te recomiendo que lo leas completo. Traducido al español simple, en `verMatriz`
estas leyendo pasado el tamaño de `mat`.

Con esto redujimos el problema a esta única función:

```cpp
void verMatriz(int (*matrizA)[COL], int nfil, int ncol) {
    int i, j;
    printf("\nNumeros introducidos: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < nfil; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; i++) {
            printf("%3d", matrizA[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

La otra herramienta que te recomiendo es `clang-tidy`. Este revisa tu código
buscando errores comunes, y te informa de ellos. En algunos casos incluso los
puede solucionar automáticamente. En este caso, al pasar tu código por
`clang-tidy` nos da como resultado (entre muchos otros avisos):

```
C:\Users\pabsa\tempc\.\main.c:71:21: warning: variables 'j' and 'ncol' used in loop condition not modified in loop body [clang-diagnostic-for-loop-analysis]
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; i++) {
```

Estas usando `j` en el loop, pero en ningún momento lo incrementas. Si te das
cuenta, colocaste `i++` en lugar de `j++`. Esto resulta en que `i` se
incrementara infinitamente, haciendo que en algún punto aquí:

```
    printf("%3d", matrizA[i][j]);
```

Leas pasado la memoria que tienes asignada para `mat`, generando el error
anteriormente mencionado. Corrigiendo el typo, el programa debería correr
correctamente.

En realidad te recomiendo que aprendas a usar estas herramientas. Desde que vi
en el comentario que las entradas tendrían que ser `4` y luego todo cincos
hasta que encontré la solución al problema no pasaron ni 5 minutos, esto
gracias a que las herramientas me lo dejaron en bandeja de plata.

Comment: muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta del error de la i. Ahora sí que me muestra la matriz con números, no con los que corresponden, pero eso lo puedo mirar yo, que seguro es alguna cuenta que tengo puesta mal. Cuando tenga tiempo libre seguro me pongo con los programas que me has mencionado, porque ya veo que son muy útiles. De nuevo, muchas gracias.